# kivy: why cannot I change the color of my rectangle?

Tags: python, kivy

Here is a method that is supposed to draw the canvas of a label:

```
def update_canvas(self):
    c = self.canvas.after
    c.clear()
    with c:
        Color([1, 1, 1, 1])
        Line(points=[self.point_from, self.point_to])
        if self.texture:
            Color([1, 0, 0, 1]) # RED RECTANGLE!
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            Color([1, 1, 1, 1])
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, texture=self.texture, size=self.texture.size)
```

The label used as a tooltip which also has a line pointing to the tooltipped item. The above version produces this output:

[image]

If I comment out the Rectangle instruction after the RED COLOR line, this is displayed:

[image]

Please note that the text's label is rendered twice, because I have also added a Rectangle(texture=self.texture) instruction, but that is for testing only.

The Label itself is added to the window with this simple call:

```
Windows.add_widget(label)
```

The question is this: why is my rectangle not red? (Actually I want it to be half transparent.)

Comment: Actually, I cannot change the color of anything. (e.g. the text or the line pointing to the text)

Comment: I'm ot quite sure what's wrong, but why do things this way at all? Why not just draw your rectangle in the canvas.before?

Comment: Canvas of which widget? The tooltip is added to the global Window for a reason: it is floating above all widgets, and can overlap others. In the screenshot you can see that it is overlapping several other widgets. In order to do this, it must be added to the global window.

Comment: The canvas of the label.

Comment: It is the canvas of the label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a list `[]` to `Color()`, while `Color` expects at least 3 parameters rgb, rgba, rgb + mode or rgba + mode

try this:

```
def update_canvas(self):
    c = self.canvas.after
    c.clear()
    with c:
        Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
        Line(points=[self.point_from, self.point_to])
        if self.texture:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 1) # RED RECTANGLE!
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, texture=self.texture, size=self.texture.size)
```

If you want a half transparent rectangle change the rgba to `1,0,0,.5`

Comment: @nagylzs not at all many people are facing this issue, because in the kv language **Color** accepts all,lists even tuples