# Why can't I control the color of a rectangle using a variable in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am creating a program in using the kivy framework and want to be able to control the color of rectangles using a variable but whenever I try the rectangle appears as its default white.

This is the code I am attempting to implement (in the actual program color is a variable set elsewhere). I looked int he kivy documentation but from what i saw Rectangle only has the pos and size tags so you cannot control color that way.

```
color =(33/255, 36/255, 52/255, 1)
#create backround for bottom grid layout
with bottom_grid_layout.canvas.before:
     #Color(33/255, 36/255, 52/255, 1)
      Color(color)
      self.rectangles = Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=(Window.width*2, 100))
```

Elsewhere in my code I have

```
save_button = Button(text='Save', size_hint=(1,.1),color = (primary_color) , background_color(button_accent_color))
```

and this works perfectly. As a note the reason I am not using a .kv file it to make updating the colors and sizes of elements easier to follow within the program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kivy: why cannot I change the color of my rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250357/kivy-why-cannot-i-change-the-color-of-my-rectangle)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add an asterisk before the reference to color to unpack the tuple.

This is the fixed code.

```
color =(33/255, 36/255, 52/255, 1)
#create backround for bottom grid layout
with bottom_grid_layout.canvas.before:
      Color(*color)
      self.rectangles = Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=(Window.width*2, 100))
```